# Cryptsetup waiting for encrytped source device /swapfile

Tags: swap, cryptsetup, cryptswap

I tried to comment on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254772/cryptsetup-waiting-for-encrypted-source-device-swapfile-fstab-empty) post but I don't have enough reputation. I'm having the same issue as that user, except that I can't find my /etc/crypttab directory and I can't find my /etc/fstab directory either.

Some additional info:
I have several drives in my PC, and I believe I'm mounting the right one when I follow the answer in the linked post. However, when I get to `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot/efi` I get a "mount point does not exist" error.

Comment: just a few comments: /etc/fstab is a file not a directory. Unless you deleted it it is present in any Ubuntu installation. Maybe you should google about the mount command. nvme0n1p1 is a device name - that is likely different on any computer. /mnt/boot/efi is just folder that you must have created before. It should be empty. Its alled a "mount point", I don't know your background, but when I moved from windows "Mount point" was a very confusing concept for me because most explanations made if more complex than it really is..